# How Can I Pass Image from one activity to another android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to pass high-quality images from one activity to another.

This is my main activity to pass the image.

```
package com.maymaps.picturestudio;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private AdView mAdView;

    private Button button1, button2, button3;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 2;

    String currentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue, this.getTheme()));
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));

        }


        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        AdSize adSize = new AdSize(300, 50);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {


            openGallery();


        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {


            openCamera();


        }


        if (view.getId() == R.id.button3) {


        }


    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        getIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

    }

    private void openCamera() {


        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File...
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

        if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (reqCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    //Starting activity (ImageViewActivity in my code) to preview image
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, result.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", photo);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else if (reqCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();

                    //Starting activity (ImageViewActivity in my code) to preview image
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, result.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ImageUri", imageUri.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

                }
            }
        }
```

Receive activity

```
package com.maymaps.picturestudio;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class result extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        Uri selectedImgUri = getIntent().getData();


        String[] selectedImgPath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImgUri,
                selectedImgPath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int indexCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(selectedImgPath[0]);
        String imgPath = cursor.getString(indexCol);
        cursor.close();
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath));

        /* Getting Image from Camera from Main Activity */
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Uri CapturedImgUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        imageView.setImageURI(CapturedImgUri);
        }
    }
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.maymaps.picturestudio">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PictureStudio">
        <activity
            android:name=".result"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash_Screen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know how to solve this. If any talented people know this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the following design pattern;
You can have a singleton class that can also the assignment of this image from whatever activity or fragment of your choice.

For example; let this be your singleton

```
public class ActivityHolder {

    private static ActivityHolder instance = null;

    private ActivityHolder() {
    }

    public static ActivityHolder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ActivityHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
    public ImageView imageView;
    

}
```

You can use the above class as follows;

Assuming you want to access the image content in the first activity i.e MainActivity.

```
ActivityHolder.getInstance().imageView = "some image object here"
```

Then in your resulting activity, you can access this image by calling the sigleton image view. So your image assignment might look like ;
ImageView imageView = ActivityHolder.getInstance().imageView